# React Widget in React WebApps / Zendesk widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zendesk

I ran into trouble yesterday, trying to make the zendesk widget work in my react web app. The config took me 2s (just some line to add to my index.html), and the widget appears as expected.

However...when i "clicked on it" i got a well knowing error : "duplicate react-id 0.3 ...". After some digging, i found that Zendesk team uses - as me - a react based stack for this widget.

I found an issue related to that : https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2713 and i wanted to know if there was some solution out there ^^

Thanks in advance

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue was fixed in React 15 rc2

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3916#issuecomment-198564434